# How to change the color of a pattern or texture in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, patterns, texture

How would I go about replicating the following pattern in Photoshop, with a different background color than this gray one?

Of course, it would be best if the pattern could be on its separate layer, so it can be compatible with *any* background color.

[image: Monotone Criss Cross Pencil Shade Pattern]

I've tried using the pen/pencil tools to draw some lines and then blurring them and reducing the opacity, but it never looks quite like this.

**How can I reproduce this pattern with a background colour of my choice?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this one is made by filters I am not sure but you can get similar effect using water paper filter

`filter > sketch > water paper`

just create your background of any color and then apply this filter.

you can maximize the values(highlighted in red) as well to get your desired output.

[image]

hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `Blend Modes` to non-destructively achieve this

1. Create a new PSD in Photoshop and add your texture or image pattern as the first layer.

   > It doesn't have to be the `Background` layer but it can depending how you choose to open it, and if you add it above the blank background layer you don't need to do anything with that background layer.

   [image]
2. Create a new `Solid Color` layer above the texture/pattern layer and choose the colour you desire when the Color Picker pops up.

   [image]
3. Click on the `Blend Mode` dropdown list at the top of the layers panel. After some quick experimentation, I found `Overlay` to be quite satisfactory for darker colours, while `Soft Light` was best for lighter colours.

   > It's as easy as cycling through the blend modes to find the one that most suits your needs. If you find one that's close, there are a thousand other ways to adjust the brightness, contrast, hue, saturation, vibrance, and much more with additional `Fill or Adjustment` layers placed above the existing layers.

   [image]

[image: red-sketch-pattern][image: blue-sketch-pattern][image: green-sketch-pattern][image: yellow-sketch-pattern]

Red version = `#ff0000` + `Overlay`

Blue version = `#1200ff` + `Overlay`

Green version = `#24ff00` + `Soft Light`

Yellow version = `#fcff00` + `Soft Light`

<sub>It is Photoshop CC, I've just changed the interface colours for an old school vibe. :)</sub>